# Equivalence relation and partitions

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, set-partition

Define an equivalence relation on the set R that partitions the real line into subsets of length 1.

Comment: $x\sim y$ if $x,y\in[n,n+1)$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$

Comment: I just really didn't know how to start with this problem. That is why I post just the problem.

Comment: @therexists You posted really good questions before, showing work and all. Maybe you could have tried and do the same here. For example, do you know that giving an equivalence relation on $\Bbb R$ amounts to partitioning it into disjoint sets?

Comment: Not much... If you want to write a brief explanation about that, I will really happy to take notes. :-) If you don't, I will google it more myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually easiest to work backwards on this problem.  We first define the ste of equivalence classes, $$\{[n,n+1):n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ and say $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ are equivalent if they belong to the same equivalence class.

Any [set partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) gives rise to an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Partitions_and_equivalence_relations) in this way.

(This is the same as Stefan H.'s comment, but there's not much else you can do, other than shift the segments.  Or perhaps you could break them into disjoint segments with total length $1$.)

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate that! : ))